# How do you get rajawali to work (tutorial 1 on git)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, rajawali

I am quite new to android development, I know the basics activities, maps, sqlite, etc.
I would like to be able to implement some 3D objects to be able to interact with within my apps. After a bit of searching I found that rajawali seems to be the best method. As you do I started with the first tutorial and reading the source code from the example docs. 
Where I have become lost is I have followed the tutorial word for word and and I cant run the application due to errors in the script. If anybody has used Rajawali before I would appreiate some pointers as to where I have gone wrong. (the tutorial was last updated 2 month ago so its quite recent). [Tutorial](https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali/wiki/Tutorial-01----Basic-Setup-&-a-Sphere)

Here is my source code

MainActivity:

```
package rajawali.tutorials;

import rajawali.RajawaliActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends RajawaliActivity {
    private Renderer mRenderer;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mRenderer = new Renderer(this);
        mRenderer.setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView);
        super.setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }   
}
```

Renderer:

```
package rajawali.tutorials;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import rajawali.lights.DirectionalLight;
import rajawali.materials.textures.ATexture.TextureException;
import rajawali.materials.textures.Texture;
import rajawali.primitives.Sphere;
import rajawali.renderer.RajawaliRenderer;

public class Renderer extends RajawaliRenderer {

    private DirectionalLight mLight;
    Sphere mSphere;

    public Renderer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFrameRate(60);
    }
    public void initScene() {
        mLight = new DirectionalLight(1f, 0.2f, -1.0f);
        mLight.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        mLight.setPower(2);

        try {
            *DiffuseMaterial* material = new *DiffuseMaterial*(); //there is an error here (DiffuseMaterial cannot be rsolved as a type)
            material.addTexture(new *Texture(R.drawable.earthtruecolor_nasa_big)*);  //here (constructor Texture(int) cannot be defined)
            mSphere = new Sphere(1, 24, 24);
            mSphere.setMaterial(material);
            mSphere.*addLight(mLight)*;  //and here (The method addLight(DirectionalLight) is undefined for the type Sphere)
            addChild(mSphere);
        } catch (TextureException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getCurrentCamera().setZ(4.2f);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
        super.onDrawFrame(glUnused);
        mSphere.setRotY(mSphere.getRotY() + 1);
    }

}
```

I don't realy want to be spoon feed code if I can help it but it appears that the error is in the 'DiffuseMaterial'. Why is this or is there a better way of manipulating 3D objects other than using min3D or Rajawali?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also have been trying to run this rajawali tutorial using next code.

Class **RajawaliTutorialActivity**

```
package rajawali.tutorials;

import rajawali.RajawaliActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RajawaliTutorialActivity extends RajawaliActivity {

    public RajawaliTutorialRenderer mRenderer; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mRenderer = new RajawaliTutorialRenderer(this);
        mRenderer.setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView);
        super.setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }
}
```

Class **RajawaliTutorialRenderer**

```
package rajawali.tutorials;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;

import rajawali.Camera;
import rajawali.Object3D;
import rajawali.lights.DirectionalLight;
import rajawali.materials.Material;
import rajawali.materials.textures.ATexture.TextureException;
import rajawali.materials.textures.Texture;
import rajawali.primitives.Sphere;
import rajawali.renderer.RajawaliRenderer;

public class RajawaliTutorialRenderer extends RajawaliRenderer {

    public DirectionalLight light;
    public Object3D sphere;
    public Context context;
    public Camera camera;

    public RajawaliTutorialRenderer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        setFrameRate(60);
    }

    public void initScene() {
        light = new DirectionalLight(1f, 0.2f, -1.0f); // set the direction
        light.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        light.setPower(2);

        try{
            Material material = new Material();
            material.addTexture(new Texture("earthColors", R.drawable.earthtruecolor_nasa_big));
            material.setColorInfluence(0);
            sphere = new Sphere(1, 24, 24);
            sphere.setMaterial(material);
            getCurrentScene().addLight(light);
            super.addChild(sphere);
        } catch (TextureException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        getCurrentCamera().setZ(4.2f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
        super.onDrawFrame(glUnused);
        sphere.setRotY(sphere.getRotY() + 1);
    }
}
```

See that changes are:

1. declare `sphere` object as `Object3D` instead `Sphere`.
2. change `DiffuseMaterial` by `Material` for material declaration.
3. change parameters to get `Texture`. First parameter is an custom identifier and second  parameter is the resource id.
4. add the line `material.setColorInfluence(0);` after load texture, if this line isn't added, the "heart" becomes red (I'm not sure why).
5. replace `sphere` object by scene object (accessing with `getCurrentScene` method) to call `addLight` method.
6. Add try/catch for line `material.addTexture()` as this method now throws a TextureException
7. add `getCurrentCamera().setZ(4.2f);` to the end of initScene

Comment: That's fantastic thank you. I wonder why the tutorial doesn't work. Are the rest of the tutorials like this?

Comment: Not sure, i didn't try to do another tutorial, but it looks as the tutorial was made for an previous version of rajawali.

Comment: super.addChild doesn't seem to work anymore. `getCurrentScene().addChild` does work.

Comment: I have posted a link to this answer on the Google+ community site here=>https://plus.google.com/103981330238857753450/posts/eBATwpQJ8St

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this has to do with the version of `Rajawali`.

On [this page](https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali/wiki/Importing-Rajawali-and-RajawaliExamples) it says not to use the `master` branch:

> Whether you choose to clone or download, you probably will want to use one of the release tags. The master branch of both the library and examples is used for development and should be considered unstable for production code. When we release a stable version, it will be tagged. If you are cloning, you can simply checkout a tag.

If you cloned `Rajawali` using `git`, you'll want to checkout from a tag. To list the tags:

```
$ git tag
v0.9
```

At the time of writing, `v0.9` is your only choice.

```
$ git checkout v0.9
```

Now you'll have `DiffuseMaterial` available. However, some of the other classes are still missing.

EDIT:

It looks like this tutorial neither applies to `v0.9` nor the latest master branch. I made a working version of tutorial 1, which [you can find linked here](https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali/issues/1196).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the RajawaliExamples application I wrote, which is composed of contributed examples, as a demonstration of using the master branch.

https://github.com/MasDennis/RajawaliExamples

Also to clarify on Deans quote, the statement made there is dissuade people from freaking out when the API changed underneath them which was mostly relevant when jwoolston was making large changes to support scene graphs. The bulk of that work is done and if ever finished, the api is likely to change significantly from its current state as the other major items are already complete. Such items are pieces like animation, more parsing options, flexible rendering, etc.